# Are all the command in my cron job being executed?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am running the following command in my wordpress update script

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo wp cli update
sudo chmod 644 /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-root-dir/wp-config.php;
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-root-dir;
wp plugin update --all --path=/var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-root-dir;
wp theme update-all --path=/var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-root-dir;
wp core update --path=/var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-root-dir;
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/example.com/public_html/wp-root-dir
```

and I have my cron job set to run at `3:05am` everyday

```
5 3 * * * /home/ubuntu/update.sh | mail -s "Wordpress Has been updated" myemail@email.com
```

But when I get the email I only get the following message:

```
 Success: WP-CLI is at the latest version.
```

But I should be getting more messages like:

```
Success: WP-CLI is at the latest version.
Success: Plugin already updated.
Success: WordPress is up to date.
```

The above is what i get when I run `./update.sh`

Are my commands being executed when my job runs, and if so how can I get all the output messages emailed to me?

Comment: which user installed the cron job?

Comment: The user was Ubuntu

Comment: you run command with sudo, you should install the job in root's crontab by `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: you should modify `mail` to `/usr/bin/mail`

Comment: @Ben That is the command I run I misunderstood you. I do run the command sudo crontab -e

Comment: @Ben I am receiving emails I am just not getting all the message out put

Comment: related link: https://superuser.com/questions/871704/why-does-root-cron-job-script-need-sudo-to-run-properly

Comment: @Ben Oh I see the issue. The wp commands are not being picked up by cron. That’s why I am not getting the message out returned in an email.